# как практиковаться чтобы лучше запоминать

Tags: веб-программирование

как практиковаться  чтобы лучше запоминать всё эту огромную информацию , подскажите эффективный метод

Comment: Учить стихи. Рекомендую стихи русских поэтов. Начните с Пушкина: *"И он к устам моим приник, И вырвал ..."*.

Comment: интересная мысль :)

Comment: - моя. Дарю, пользуйтесь.

Comment: Лучшая практика - отвечать на SO :))

Answer (score 0):

На более серьезной ноте.

Не стремитесь запомнить эту "огромную информацию". Читайте. Важно, чтобы после такого чтения, позднее, когда Вы столкнетесь с проблемой, имеющей отношение к прочитанному, у Вас возникало ощущение, что Вы об этом читали. А уж после этого, в наш век, найти эти материалы и освежить в памяти - нетрудно.